# C++ pthread, two threads read a global variable

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

If there are two threads that just read a global variable, is it necessary to use mutex to lock and unlock the global variable?

Answer (score 7):

If the threads are only reading the variable and *nobody* is writing to it (not one of the threads, not someone else), then you're perfectly fine without locks. If any concurrent modification could happen, then everyone (including pure readers) must be synchronised somehow - by a mutex, a read/write lock or in some other way.

Answer (score 5):

In general, exclusive access is required to *prevent one from seeing an inconsistent state*. For a reader thread, this means avoiding *partial reads*.

What does that mean ? Imagine that you have a value stored on two (atomic) integers, for example coordinates.

```
int i = 3;
int j = 4;
```

Now, we are going to read `i` and `j` whilst they undergo modification, more precisely when a `Writer` thread want to move in a diagonal fashion from `(3, 4)` to `(4, 5)`:

```
Reader     Writer
  |          |
  |        i = 4
  |          |
i = 4     <pause>
j = 4        |
  |        j = 5
  |          |
```

This is called a *partial read*: the `Reader` thread has gotten information that the object is at `(4, 4)` even though *it was never there*. I'll let you think what occurs if those coordinates are used to compute the trajectory of a plane...

Avoiding *partial reads* however is fairly easy: mutations should be seen atomically.

- if there is no mutation (for the duration of the reads) then you can just read
- if there are mutations, you need a mutual exclusion mechanism (such as a reader/writer mutex)

And thus, to answer your question, if the only accesses are read accesses, the no synchronization is required. But if you sometimes (even infrequently) modify the information read, then you need some mechanism.

Comment: Similar to the above question. For example, I have two threads. Each thread calls a method of an object to get its property, for example A->getName(). In this case, is mutex necessary?

Comment: @JohnSimpson: A method is nothing more than syntactic sugar for a friend function taking `*this` as first parameter, so the question is just about *what does the function do ?* If the method only access the object in read-only method, then it is okay, so if the method is `const` or the function takes the object through a const-pointer or const-reference it should be okay (beware of `mutable` attributes not designed with multi-threaded safety in mind)

Answer (score 2):

If they're *just* reading, then you don't need locking.

Answer (score 2):

If they are just reading then no need of lock but when that is not the case then I think mutex will ensure that reading thread will not eat resources while it has nothing to do.

Something like this:-

```
Thread1() {
Mutex_lock();
Process global_variable;
Unlock_mutex();
}
```

Similarly for `Thread2`

**On a side note:-**

Mutex is generally used to prevent multiple threads from accessing shared memory or other resources concurrently. Also to remember that it does not lock anything by itself